# InDesign: call script via grep style

Tags: grep, adobe-indesign

I don't know if this is possible but this is what I'm trying to achieve.
I use a lot of scripts in InDesign. Every time I run a script I have to go to the pannel and double click on the script.

If I can call on a script via a grep style I would have a real time feature that can execute scripts while building.

Please let me know if you have an idea!

Comment: It is a bit confusing, what are you trying to do. On the first look - there is no easy option. You might look at EventListeners, but that is going to need some work. In the latest versions of InDesign you can build your own panels and add your scripts there. In the older versions you can add  menus and sub-menus to InDesign to call your own scripts.

Comment: Thnx for your reply. If you use GREP styles you are (as you know) able to change markup while typing. So if I'd set a GREP style that changes the combination of "abc" to magenta and a word contains the "abc" then it would instantly change. I want to be able to type in "abc" and the a GREP style would run a script.

Comment: Again, there is no easy option to do this, and EventListeners are the thing you need to look up.

Comment: okay I'm going to take a look at them

Comment: I did try this kind of real time text changes in order to ensure my former company website was always formatted as expected. But it would take so many ressources that I finally remove it and just forced myself to double check ;)

Comment: Well it's not really about the checking. It's just to make life easier. I get documents that contain hundreds of pages. I want to load them in and get the majority of basic things done. I think if I get up to the point where I want to do advanced things I need a faster computer :-)